# Change values of a table using urllib

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to change the values in a table using `urllib`. I believe the way to do this is by using post request. However I am having no success whatsoever and am completely lost.

Any help you can share is appreciated.

Here is the page I am trying to edit (editme.php)

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td id="changme">1</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am running things locally and I want to change the value in cell w/ `id="changeme"` to something else. I am trying to do that using this:

```
import urllib
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

values = urllib.urlencode({'changeme' : 'i have changed'})
f = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost/editme.php",values)
readdata = urllib.urlopen("http://localhost/editme.php")
print  BeautifulSoup(readdata).prettify()
```

Comment: -1 for not knowing the difference between client and server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does not make any sense what you are asking. You have to change the template or whatever is rendering your table on the SERVER and not through download/upload.

Answer (score 0):

Em... sorry, but there is no way you'll change that table value via urllib, unless the php script does that. And the editme.php is a "pure" html file.